# Convert ser.read output to valid elements in a list - Python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I need to read data from the serial port and insert it into a list from location 1 to 16.

```
rxbuf[1:16] = ser.read(16)
```

Although I get an error as below:

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

If I print the output of the serial port,

```
rxbuf=ser.read(16)
```

the output looks like this:

```
b'\xf2\x97\x00\x00\x8er\x9a\xc0\x14\xff\xff|:F\x18\x00'
```

Is there a way to convert the above, and place it in the list?
What I need is `rxbuf[1] = 0xF2, rxbuf[2] = 0x97` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

rxbuf=ser.read(16)
rxbuf = ser.read(16).split("\") --- since your response is split by '\' forward slash
It should print like this....
rxbuf[1] = 0xF2
rxbuf[2] = 0x97

https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-how-to-split-a-string/

Comment: Thanks Praful, your answer prompted me to the right answer.  rxbuf = ' '.join([hex(i) for i in rxbuf_len]).split()   This is the solution.